# how to extend the numpy array in loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

```
import numpy as np

attendance = np.array([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])

name_list = np.array(["Ali","Ahmad","Beng","Chris","Sita","Marion","Stephen","Cobby","Akmal","Nita"])

day_list = np.array(["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"])

attendance=np.reshape(attendance,[10,7])
```

an the output for attendance for a week

```
 array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

i want to append each name in name_list to most-left in each item in attendance

Comment: Objective not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: i want to append 2d  numpy array attendance [1 1 1 0 0 0 0] with each name_list numpay array elements

Comment: Can you edit your question and remove unnecessary ```print()``` statements. Also provide a sample output.

Comment: Also, what is ```x0```

Comment: already edited the post to more understanding

Comment: ```['Ali', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'],                                                                                                   
       ['Ahmad', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']``` do you want something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
C = np.concatenate((name_list.reshape(-1,1),attendance), axis=1)
print(C)
```

Output

```
[['Ali' '1' '0' '0' '1' '1' '1' '0']                                                                                                                 
 ['Ahmad' '1' '0' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                               
 ['Beng' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '0']                                                                                                                
 ['Chris' '1' '0' '0' '1' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                               
 ['Sita' '1' '1' '1' '0' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                                
 ['Marion' '1' '0' '0' '0' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                              
 ['Stephen' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                             
 ['Cobby' '1' '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']                                                                                                               
 ['Akmal' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']                                                                                                               
 ['Nita' '0' '0' '0' '1' '1' '1' '1']]
```

Comment: Further, you can add following if req. ```day_list = np.concatenate((np.array([""]), day_list))
A = np.concatenate((day_list.reshape(1,-1), C), axis=0)
print(A)```